# Ubuntu 22.04 does not install selected packages

Tags: package-management

I installed 22.04 from scratch. Then I downloaded the latest version (13.8.1) of 'mediathekview' and used software installer to install. Instead of 13.8.1 they installed version 13.2.1 from the Ubuntu distribution. I found out that this is what usually happens to every package I want to install with the installer. Always they chose the packages from Ubuntu (if any available) but the manual chosen package. There is no warning/information or a way to chose which version to install.

Comment: https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/mediathekview Yes, that's what the Ubuntu software depot provides right now. Generally the software versions for not so much popular packages are rather old in Ubuntu software depot. My guess is that there are not enough resources in Canonical to test and update to newer releases. You can go to software's web page and download the latest versiom from here; but this means that you have to manually check and update that software later on.

Comment: @FedKad the community (not Canonical) is responsible for testing and updating packages in Universe.

Comment: See https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mediathekview; the Debian maintainer has not updated the package in two years. That's why the Ubuntu repositories have an older version. This suggests that more volunteer help would be welcome. Folks who want to help can contact the package maintainer, or learn how to maintain themselves at http://mentors.debian.net

Comment: It's unclear which application you used to install mediathekview, since there is no application called "software installer". Perhaps a mistranslation? You are correct that Ubuntu Software doesn't easily install local deb packages (that's not it's purpose), but local packages are trivial to install from a shell prompt: `sudo apt install /path/to/package_name.deb`

Comment: e.g. when you just right click on the .deb and chose 'open with software install' it always chooses the file from the Ubuntu software depot but the selected file.